# Residual variance extracted from glm and lmer in R

Tags: r, variance

I am trying to take what I have read about multilevel modelling and merge it with what I know about `glm` in R. I am now using the height growth data from [here](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/support/datasets/).

I have done some coding shown below:

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)

setwd("~/Documents/r_code/multilevel_modelling/")

rm(list=ls())

oxford.df <- read.fwf("oxboys/OXBOYS.DAT",widths=c(2,7,6,1))
names(oxford.df) <- c("stu_code","age_central","height","occasion_id")
oxford.df <- oxford.df[!is.na(oxford.df[,"age_central"]),]
oxford.df[,"stu_code"] <- factor(as.character(oxford.df[,"stu_code"]))
oxford.df[,"dummy"] <- 1

chart <- ggplot(data=oxford.df,aes(x=occasion_id,y=height))
chart <- chart + geom_point(aes(colour=stu_code))

# see if lm and glm give the same estimate
glm.01 <- lm(height~age_central+occasion_id,data=oxford.df)
glm.02 <- glm(height~age_central+occasion_id,data=oxford.df,family="gaussian")
summary(glm.02)
vcov(glm.02)
var(glm.02$residual)
(logLik(glm.01)*-2)-(logLik(glm.02)*-2)
1-pchisq(-2.273737e-13,1)
# lm and glm give the same estimation
# so glm.02 will be used from now on

# see if lmer without level2 variable give same result as glm.02
mlm.03 <- lmer(height~age_central+occasion_id+(1|dummy),data=oxford.df,REML=FALSE)
(logLik(glm.02)*-2)-(logLik(mlm.03)*-2)
# 1-pchisq(-3.408097e-07,1)
# glm.02 and mlm.03 give the same estimation, only if REML=FALSE
```

`mlm.03` gives me the following output:

```
> mlm.03
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood 
Formula: height ~ age_central + occasion_id + (1 | dummy) 
   Data: oxford.df 
  AIC  BIC logLik deviance REMLdev
 1650 1667 -819.9     1640    1633
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 dummy    (Intercept)  0.000   0.0000  
 Residual             64.712   8.0444  
Number of obs: 234, groups: dummy, 1

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  142.994     21.132   6.767
age_central    1.340     17.183   0.078
occasion_id    1.299      4.303   0.302

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) ag_cnt
age_central  0.999       
occasion_id -1.000 -0.999
```

You can see that there is a variance for the residual in the `random effect` section, which I have read from `Applied Multilevel Analysis - A Practical Guide` by Jos W.R. Twisk, that this represents the amount of "unexplained variance" from the model.

I wondered if I could arrive at the same residual variance from `glm.02`, so I tried the following:

```
> var(resid(glm.01))
[1] 64.98952
> sd(resid(glm.01))
[1] 8.061608
```

The results are slightly different from the `mlm.03` output. Does this refer to the same "residual variance" stated in `mlm.03`?

Comment: This question is off topic here (should be on stackoverflow) so I voted to close but you can access the residual variance from an `lmer` model fit with `attr(VarCorr(mlm.03),"sc")^2`, since your model is named `mlm.03`. Other variance components can be accessed using the `VarCorr()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your `glm.02` and `glm.01` estimate a simple linear regression model using least squares. On the other hand, `mlm.03` is a linear mixed model estimated through maximum likelihood.
I don't know your dataset, but it looks like you use the `dummy` variable to create a cluster structure at level-2 with zero variance.

So your question has basically two answers, but only the second answer is important in your case. The models `glm.02` and `mlm.03` do *not* contain the same residual variance estimate, because...

1. The models are *usually* different (mixed effects vs. classical regression). In your case, however, the `dummy` variable seems to supress the additional variance component in the mixed model. So for me the models seem to be equal.
2. The method used to estimate the residual variance is different. `glm` uses LS, `lmer` uses ML in your code. ML estimates for the residual variance are slightly biased (resulting in smaller variance estimates). This can be solved by using REML instead of ML to estimate variance components.

Using classic ML (instead of REML), however, is still necessary and correct for the likelihood-ratio test. Using REML the comparison of the two likelihoods would not be correct.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** with `REML = TRUE` the two approaches give the same estimated residual SD.

```r
oxboys <- transform(nlme::Oxboys,
   occasion = as.numeric(Occasion),
   dummy = 1)
library(lme4)
m1 <- lm  (height~age+occasion, oxboys)
m2 <- lmer(height~age+occasion + (1|dummy), REML = TRUE, oxboys,
        control = lmerControl(check.nlev.gtr.1 = "ignore"))
```

```r
all.equal(sd(resid(m1)), sd(resid(m2)))  ## TRUE
all.equal(c(logLik(m1)), c(logLik(m2)))  ## TRUE
```

The best way to retrieve the *estimated* residual SD is `sigma()`. These are indeed different for the two models, they are what's reported in the printed output for `m2`, and they are *not* the same as the square root of the residuals, because the residuals are already mean-centered (so the denominator should be calculated differently from the usual sample SD).

```r
MASS::fractions(sd(resid(m1))/sigma(m1), cycle = 2)
[1] 231/232
```